# Dropdownlilst DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged in gridview not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Dropdownlist list is not working in my following grid.I want to change label text when  drop downlist changed dropdownlisth the label text is not working

```
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="sup_rec_id">        
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server"    ID="lblFirstLastName"  Text='<%# Eval("sup_rec_id") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">        
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server"    ID="quantity"  Text='<%# Eval("quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code">        
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server"    ID="code"  Text='<%# Eval("code") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">        
      <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
     AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>D</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

filename.Aspx.cs

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Test text";
}
```

Guide me what i do?

Comment: try removing this from <asp:Label id="Label1" ... >   'Text="Label"' My guess is that the setting of text to that label is happening after the value is being set in code behind (ie I think you are overwriting your value each time after it gets set- did you throw a break point on that selected index change and see if it is ever called accordingly?

Comment: i removed and do Text="" but not working

Comment: ok, did you do the other part? Throw a break point on that event... Does it get called when index changes? What happens when you step through?

Comment: i also throw a break point in  Label1.Text = "Test text"; but nothing show

Comment: ok so that tells me the selected index changed event isn't firing. Maybe those object's links are broken. Did you rename anything using something at some point? From what you've posted it looks like it should* work.